# Implement OnItemClick inside a SimpleCursorAdapter

Tags: android

I have a SimpleCursorAdapter Class, and I want to set an OnItemClick method everytime when the row is clicked.

The method looks like this:

```
protected void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> l, View v, int position, long id) {
            Intent listIntent = new Intent(DetailsActivity.class,this);
            listIntent.putExtra("spendino.de.ProjectDetail.position",position);

            listIntent.setData(Uri.withAppendedPath(Uri.withAppendedPath(
                    Provider.CONTENT_URI, Database.Project.NAME), Long
                    .toString(id)));

            startActivity(listIntent);
}
```

but it always gives me an error on this line: `Intent listIntent = new Intent(DetailsActivity.class,this);`
It asks me to remove the arguments.

Can anybody help me with this?

**UPDATED**

```
@Override
        public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
            View convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.listitems, null);
            convertView.setClickable(true);
            convertView.setFocusable(true);
            convertView.setBackgroundResource(android.R.drawable.menuitem_background);
            convertView.setOnItemClickListener(ProjectsList.this);

            return convertView;
        }
```

the first solution gave me no error, but when I set the method on my View, it says that setOnItemClickListener is undefined for convertView

**UPDATED**

```
convertView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                 public void onClick(View view) {
                  Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), DetailsActivity.class);
                  myIntent.putExtra("spendino.de.ProjectDetail.position",position);
                  myIntent.setData(Uri.withAppendedPath(Uri.withAppendedPath(
                            Provider.CONTENT_URI, Database.Project.NAME), Long
                            .toString(id)));
                  view.getContext().startActivity(myIntent);
                 }
                });
```

`setOnClickListener` isn't working, I got an error on 'position' and 'id' how should I declare it?
Because those 2 things are mainly found on the `setOnItemClickListener` method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Intent listIntent = new Intent(DetailsActivity.class,this);
```

this should be the other way around

```
Intent listIntent = new Intent(this, DetailsActivity.class);
```

or use `MyActivity.this` as first argument.

```
covertView.setOnClickListener()
```

use this.. onItemClickListener is for listView. but the convertView is only a list Item..

Comment: sorry it doesn't help, it still says 'The constructor Intent is undefined'

Comment: the first argument is a context.. so you need to pass may be YourActivity.this as first argument..

Comment: thanks it works now with the method, but I have a trouble to set it. I just updated my question, pls have a look